# Javascript (theory) - Can the Proxy pattern be used to add extra functionality?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, refactoring

I commonly use the Proxy pattern to avoid API calls

```
const bankAPI = () => ({
   getUserData: () => { name: "Victorio" },
})

function bankAPIProxy = () => {
   const bankAPI = bankAPI();
   const cache = {};
 
   getUserData = () => {
      if(cache.userData) return cache.userData; // Save API Calls
      cache.userData = bankAPI.getUserData();
   }
}
```

But, can this same pattern be used to add extra functionality and still be considered a Proxy?

What about, if instead of implementing that, the Proxy looks like this:

```
function bankAPIProxy = () => {
   const bankAPI = bankAPI();
 
   getUserData = () => bankAPI.getUserData();

   newMethod = () => "Hello World!";
}
```

is this still a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy pattern is used so the client doesn't have to know if they are using a real object (subject) or a proxied one. This is why a **proxy has to have the same interface as a subject**.
This is why there should not be any additional methods - if the client relies on them, then it will be not possible to switch to the original object without additional refactor.

You can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern for more information.